# Query dynamic data with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, syntax

I got three tables: Houses, Person and PersonHouseAssignments

In my `Houses`-Table I got different columns like `HouseName`, `HouseType` and `Description`.

In `PeopleHouseAssignments` I got columns like `PersonId` and `HouseId`.

---

I now want to display this in my WPF DataGrid in the following way:

A column named `HouseNames` that contains ALL the available HouseNames from my `Houses`-Table.

I now got a checkbox in my datagrid that should assign the currently selected person to the house.

```
[ ] House1
[x] House2
[ ] House3
[x] House4
```

This Person is assigned to House2 and House4, because the table "PersonHouseAssignments" has two rows:

```
PersonId | HouseId
1        |    2
1        |    4
```

How should I create my LINQ Query?

I've already tried something like this, but this didn't work:

```
from p in _dataContext.Houses
from a in _dataContext.PersonHouseAssignments
select new {HouseNames = p.HouseName, IsAssigned = a.HouseId == p.Id, Description = a.Description }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your query would be specific to a particular person? Namely, the `IsAssigned` value of each item in your returned collection would be `true` if that particular person is assigned to the house named `HouseName`? In that case, you could use a nested subquery:

```
int personId = 1;

var query = 
    from h in _dataContext.Houses
    select new 
    {
        HouseName = h.HouseName, 
        IsAssigned = 
        (
           from a in _dataContext.PersonHouseAssignments
           where a.HouseId == h.Id && a.PersonId == personId
           select a
        ).Any()
    };
```

**Edit**: If you want to include the `Description` from `PersonHouseAssignments`, you could use:

```
int personId = 1;

var query =
    from h in _dataContext.Houses
    let a = 
    (                
        from pha in _dataContext.PersonHouseAssignments
        where pha.HouseId == h.Id && pha.PersonId == personId
        select pha
    ).FirstOrDefault()
    select new
    {
        HouseName = h.HouseName,
        Description = a != null ? a.Description : "",
        IsAssigned = a != null
    };
```

Comment: What about the Description column?

Comment: This is working well in our application, many thanks for this!

Comment: If you’re issuing the query against a database backend _and_ you need to include the `Description` column, then you might want to compare the SQL generated by the above query with the one generated by @JoeTuskan. It might be the case that Joe’s left outer join gets translated better to SQL than my nested subquery.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [GroupJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301847.aspx) for this:

```
var query = from h in _dataContext.Houses
            join a in _dataContext.PersonHouseAssignments 
            on h.Id equals a.HouseId into assignments
            select new 
            {
               HouseName = p.HouseName, 
               IsAssigned = assignments.Any(),
               //..
            }
```

Comment: `IsAssigned` will always be `true`. This would not include records where the join did not find a match.

Comment: I wouldn't think so - by using a group join `assignments` may be an empty collection - that will be the case for houses that don't have a match in the `PersonHouseAssignments` table

Answer (score 3):

Use a join with [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx)

```
var query = from house in _dataContext.Houses
            join assignment in _dataContext.PersonHouseAssignments
            on house.Id equals assignment.HouseId into results
            from r in results.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new 
            {
               HouseNames = house.HouseName, 
               IsAssigned = r != null, 
               Description = r != null ? r.Description : string.Empty
            }
```

This will generate SQL with a left outer join to include `Description`.

Comment: Thank you, Joe. This is working well, too. Sadly I can't find any performance-differences from your solution and the one from Douglas. And since I can't select two answers as the right ones and Douglas answered first, I'm selecting his post as the answer. I still gave you an "Up-vote", though ;-)

Comment: Hey @SeToY, no problems man! I honestly enjoy just throwing an answer in the ring. I'm glad you got your problem resolved.